# Custom rule set items set to action "Info" still appear as "warning" in *error list* (not as "messages") Why?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis, error-list

i created a custom rule set in Visual Studio 2017 (latest) and set some IDs of the "*Managed Binary Analysis*" (i.e. *CA1305*) in the *Action* column from ***Warning*** to ***Info***.

However when i run the code analysis on the project it still appears as a ***warning*** in the "Error List" pane. Why is that?

I would expect it to appear as a ***message***. What's wrong?

(Double checked that i selected this rule set for my project as well as having saved the file. Also already tried to restart VS and rebuild the project)

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I too am experiencing the same issue.